# WPF App Fails With System.MissingMethodException

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I made a WPF app that uses Web Services. It is failing on all computers except the dev machine with the message -- System.MissingMethodException. I guess the point where it fails is the point where it tried to access the Remote webservice (website).

Has anyone had any experience with WPF and webservices? Should I spend 2 more days porting it to .Net Winforms, or should I keep trying to make it run?

The problem is, in Vista all I see is 'This application has experienced an error and will shut down' and in XP I just a system error dialog and I can't point out where the error is.

My guess is that there is some DLL which is on my PC and not on other people's PC which has the missing method causing the error.

I made this using .Net 3.5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have identified the most probable cause of your problem: a mismatch between the installed libraries on your dev machine and the prod machines.

You can use the fuslogvw.exe to enable Fusion to log binding errors.

Also check whether you have installed the same (versions of) .NET framework everywhere (SP1?)

Comment: I have SP1 on my machine, and almost certainly it's not on the target machines. Let me get that checked and I will be back with a hurrah! if it works.

Comment: It was SP1 missing. It worked with SP1 installed, though it now doesn't work at all for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use SP1? Is SP1 installed on the target machine?

Getting a full stack trace would allow you to diagnose this further.

Comment: I have sp1 on my machine and not on the target machine... let me check if it works.